# How do I pass Text instead of URL in the Smmry API?

Tags: javascript, php

this is a very specific questions so I am not sure if there is anyone that can answer, but I have to try anyway.
So the reddit tldr bot uses the [Smmry API](https://smmry.com/api) to summarize content. I am trying to make something similar. The problem is in the documentation it only shows URLs as a possible parameter. Does anyone know how I could just pass a string of text?
I tried emailing them but got no response.

[The home page of Smmry](https://smmry.com/) lets you pass just text so I am sure you can do it, There is also an example in PHP but I have 0 knowledge of PHP. Here is their PHP example:

```php
$text = "Your long text goes here...";

$ch = curl_init("https://api.smmry.com/&SM_API_KEY=X");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Expect:")); // See Note
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "sm_api_input=".$text);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 20);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);
$return = json_decode(curl_exec($ch), true);
curl_close($ch);
```

Here is the sample code I am using for the request in javascript. YOURKEY is a placeholder for the key each person gets.

```js
const axios = require('axios')

axios.post('https://api.smmry.com?SM_API_KEY=YOURKEY', {
})
    .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response.data.sm_api_content);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the string you would like to summarize as a `key=pair` value as a single string.

The added headers mimic the example in the API docs.

```
const axios = require('axios');

const text = 'A very long text to summarize..';

axios.post(
  'https://api.smmry.com?SM_API_KEY=YOURKEY', 
  `sm_api_input=${text}`, 
  {
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      'Expect': '100-continue'
    }
  }
)
.then(function (response) {
  console.log(response.data.sm_api_content);
})
.catch(function (error) {
  console.log(error);
});
```

Comment: Tried it, it doesn't work. It says sm_api_error: 1, sm_api_message: 'INSUFFICIENT VARIABLES'

Comment: That's unfortunate. And that's with both `Content-Type` headers?

Comment: I used your key to test it out and figured it out. We were sending the data as JSON, but we needed to send it as query parameters in a single string.

Comment: Wow thank you so much. It worked! I don't know what to say, I didn't expect anyone to be able to help me. I really appreciate it :)